# Hide products from subcategories in categories woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

when I enter a category it shows me all the subcategories and the products in the subcategories. I want to show only the subcategories and hide the products of these.

I have used this code but it does not show me the subcategories if there is no product added from the main category.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

If there is no product in the main category, it does not show the subcategories.
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW7bk.png)

Here I add a product to the main category and show the subcategories.
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrfzW.png)

I would like to show the subcategories even if there are no products in the main category. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: WooCommerce has customizer settings to choose what to display on the category and shop page, from the settings you can choose **Show subcategories** for your need, unless you have a special need to write custom code to do the same.

Comment: @VijayHardaha have tried this feature but it doesn't get what I need as it hides the main category products also. And I need in the category to show subcategories and products from the main category. But not to show the products of the subcategory. That's why I resort to the code. [View example](https://i.ibb.co/9rVMX6M/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the way by using the `pre_get_posts` hook.

Here is what you can do:

```php
function hide_products_in_subcategories($query) {
  // Check if we are on a category archive page
  if ($query->is_tax('product_cat') && $query->is_main_query()) {
    // Set the number of products per page to 0
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 0);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'hide_products_in_subcategories');
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :S

Answer (score 0):

I added this to functions.php and all is well.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.